# Boost::Log Error in Cpp / Cli Project

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, boost, c++-cli

I have a cpp project, a cpp cli project and a c# win forms project. I am using boost log lib in my native cpp project. 
When i test my project with a cpp console app, it runs and writes log successfully.

But, when i test it with cli project, i take this error :

> Error 2   error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   'boost_log-vc100-mt-gd-1_44.lib'

[I have downloaded boost lib](http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/boost-log/boost-log-1.1.zip) and I have built boost libs and it has exported libboost_log_setup-vc100-mt-gd-1_44.lib , libboost_log-vc100-mt-gd-1_44.lib files.
 
How can i fix this? How can i get 'boost_log-vc100-mt-gd-1_44.lib' files?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the error. I have built the lib files with the command below :

```
bjam --with-log variant=debug define=BOOST_LOG_USE_CHAR define=BOOST_LOG_USE_WINNT6_API stage --build-type=complete --link=
shared
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried --build-type=complete when building boost? There appear lots of different versions of each boots lib (using different versions of the C++ runtime lib etc).

I am using boost 1.49, there seems to be no log-Library (It would be nice to have it included).

Comment: In any case , I have compiled separately

Comment: I fixed the error. I have built the lib files with the command below :

    bjam --with-log variant=debug define=BOOST_LOG_USE_CHAR define=BOOST_LOG_USE_WINNT6_API stage --build-type=complete --link=shared